# How to generate a warning (not an exception)

Tags: gradle

How do I generate a warning in gradle build scripts to alert the user to something (potentially) problematic - but not mission critical.

I know you can throw exceptions like this

```
if (...) {
    throw new GradleException("something bad happened")
}
```

But what if I don't want to stop the build, but just let the user know something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work (from [docs.gradle.org](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#example_writing_your_own_log_messages)) :

**Example: Writing your own log messages**

```
logger.quiet('An info log message which is always logged.')
logger.error('An error log message.')
logger.warn('A warning log message.')
logger.lifecycle('A lifecycle info log message.')
logger.info('An info log message.')
logger.debug('A debug log message.')
logger.trace('A trace log message.')
```